# Convex polyhedron with $3$ vertices, $2$ faces and $3$ edges

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, polyhedra, solid-geometry

Can a convex polyhedron with $3$ vertices, $2$ faces and $3$ edges exist? If so, how does it look like or what's its name? My imagination just fails here...

I was reading a proof of Euler's formula (https://plus.maths.org/content/eulers-polyhedron-formula) where it boils down to showing that $V+F-E$ for the polyhedron in question equals $2$. But I'm not really sure if such a convex polyhedron can exist at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "polyhedron". If you, like me, want the faces and edges to be flat and straight, then this is impossible. You need at least four faces to make a polyhedron.

If you allow faces and edges to be curved, then you can imagine gluing two equilateral triangles edge to edge, and then "inflate" it a bit. Or, equivalently, take a sphere, call the equator an edge, and put three vertices along the same equator.

Comment: But the proof in the link I posted is based on straight polyhedra only. Does this render the proof invalid?

Comment: @MrPink No. The Euler characteristic is a requirement all convex polyhedra must obey. That does not, in any way, imply that all combinations of number of faces, edges and vertices that fulfills the Euler characteristic requirement can be realized as a polyhedron. Your 2,3,2 is an example of an unrealizeable combination.

Comment: So, "2,3,2" represents the net of *something*, for which $V+F-E$ is invariant compared to possible convex polyhedra?

Comment: @MrPink: Early on in the proof you cite (and pretty much every proof you'll see of Euler's relation), the context transitions from polyhedra to "networks" (ie, combinatorial graphs) on the plane (or sphere). Euler's formula is proven in this broader context. Although every polyhedron corresponds to a network not every network corresponds to a polyhedron ... and, therefore, not every step of the proof is about polyhedra. In particular, the fundamental $3$-$2$-$3$ network —a triangle with an "interior" face and (unbounded) "exterior" face— isn't polyhedron *per se*, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @Blue Thank you, I get it now.